# clamdscan can't read from tmp directory

Tags: php, security, file-upload, upload, antivirus

I was wondering what's wrong with my code, if I use clamscan, it works fine both reading from /tmp, or manually specified the path. but if I use clamdscan, any path from /tmp will result in error (the int result is 2). This is the code.

```
    $command = 'clamdscan ' . escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $out = '';
    $int = -1;
    exec($command, $out, $int);

    echo "\n" . $command;
    echo "\n" . $out;
    echo "\n This is int = " . $int;
    if ($int == 0) {
        // all good, code goes here uploads file as normal IE move to
        //echo "File path : ".$file."Return code : ".cl_pretcode($retcode); 
        //echo "\n";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "filesave/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "filesave/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
    } else {
        echo "\n FAILED";
    }
```

based on above code, it will failed because $int = 2. But, if I change the command to

```
//some file that is saved already in the directory
$command = 'clamdscan ' . '/abc/abc.txt';
```

It works perfectly fine.

It only failed if the command is clamdscan. if I use clamscan, temp directory is fine

any idea?

Comment: Does user running `clamd` deamon have permissions to `/tmp` ?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller hmm.. to be honest I'm not sure how to check that. please guide me. I know that clamscan works ok, so I thought it should be the same thing?

Comment: `clamscan` runs with privileges of user invoking it, however `clamdscan` relies on a demon process that usually  runs with special account with very limited privileges. Just check if `/tmp` and is s subdirectories are readable to everyone

Comment: @dev-null-dweller if that's the case, I just check it, and it's readable for everyone (777). and I try to put some file on it, and run it from command line (not through php exec function), clamdscan works fine

Comment: Hey @Harts did you found any solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick remark on using http://torquecp.sourceforge.net/phpclamcli.html as a supposedly better alternative to a DIY cli exec. The aforementioned php script does entirely rely on the syntax of the clamav response text as well.

[image: Script performs string analysis on reponse text]

Answer (score 0):

You should really just use one of the many clamd clients out there instead of relying on exec'ing a command and parsing its output, that's super fragile and will bring you nothing but headache in the future. For example:

http://torquecp.sourceforge.net/phpclamcli.html

If you are the do-it-yourself type, the clamd wire protocol is super simple (http://linux.die.net/man/8/clamd) and you could potentially write up a simple client in a couple of hours. Again, the benefit here is that it's a well defined protocol and has some nice features like a streaming call that allows you to operate the clamd service and your webapp with completely difference security credentials (heck they can even run on different boxes).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I've just had the same issue. `clamdscan` runs as user `clamav` which doesn't have permission to files in `/tmp`. There is an additional parameter `--fdpass` which runs the command as the user running the script.

Using `$command = 'clamdscan --fdpass' . escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` should run the command as the www user which will have access to the temporary file.